# Java Business address class

Tags: java

Does anyone know off-hand a simple/nice jar for business addresses?
i'd hate to write class Address { int zip; enum Country country ... blah blah }

The purpose is to keep them in a DB and recall the addresses for sending to a PDF doc. We got the PDF part covered already.

This is likely written somewhere already.

Answer (score 0):

Java's [PostalAddress](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/registry/infomodel/PostalAddress.html) might be what you want, though it is only in interface.